# Objective C ceil returns wrong value

Tags: ios

```
NSLog(@"CEIL %f",ceil(2/3));
```

should return 1. However, it shows:

```
CEIL 0.000000
```

Why and how to fix that problem? I use `ceil([myNSArray count]/3)` and it returns 0 when array count is 2.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

The same rules as C apply: `2` and `3` are ints, so `2/3` is an integer divide. Integer division truncates so `2/3` produces the integer `0`. That integer `0` will then be cast to a double precision float for the call to `ceil`, but `ceil(0)` is `0`.

Changing the code to:

```
NSLog(@"CEIL %f",ceil(2.0/3.0));
```

Will display the result you're expecting. Adding the decimal point causes the constants to be recognised as double precision floating point numbers (and `2.0f` is how you'd type a single precision floating point number).

Maudicus' solution works because `(float)2/3` casts the integer `2` to a float and C's promotion rules mean that it'll promote the denominator to floating point in order to divide a floating point number by an integer, giving a floating point result.

So, your current statement `ceil([myNSArray count]/3)` should be changed to either:

```
([myNSArray count] + 2)/3           // no floating point involved
```

Or:

```
ceil((float)[myNSArray count]/3)    // arguably more explicit
```

Comment: Yes. Or `2.0 / 3`. Type promotions run towards floating point formats.

Answer (score 10):

2/3 evaluates to 0 unless you cast it to a float.
So, you have to be careful with your values being turned to int's before you want.

```
float decValue = (float) 2/3;
NSLog(@"CEIL %f",ceil(decValue));
```

==>

```
 CEIL 1.000000
```

For you array example

```
float decValue = (float) [myNSArray count]/3;
NSLog(@"CEIL %f",ceil(decValue));
```

Answer (score 1):

It probably evaluates 2 and 3 as integers (as they are, obviously), evaluates the result (which is 0), and then converts it to float or double (which is also 0.00000). The easiest way to fix it is to type either 2.0f/3, 2/3.0f, or 2.0f/3.0f, (or without "f" if you wish, whatever you like more ;) ).

Hope it helps